# Product Schema MPN or SKU or Both

Tags: schema.org, products

I include the MPN attribute in my Product Schema but no SKU attribute as in my backend system I only use the MPN to manage my products.

I notice that my competitors include the MPN and SKU attribute in their Product Schema and they even incorrectly give the MPN value to the SKU attribute and the SKU value to the MPN attribute.
So even this is completely incorrect Google places them in a prime position in search results.

If I decide to also include the SKU attribute in my Product Schema it would be the same as the MPN value/attribute.

So is it best to just leave it as is, only the MPN, or replace the MPN attribute with the SKU attribute(the value wouldn't change) or have both MPN and SKU attribute with the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1

Google combines the information, into one large database ... for example the Samsung galaxy s23

```
    "@type": [
      "Thing",
      "ProductModel"
    ],
```

Is described in schema as both a thing and a product model. Google will match it with either type.

### The unique product number

The goal is to match with a record Google already has. The product number is considered optional in Google's database. But helpful to make an unambiguous reference. The manufacturer may have product names that are almost the same.

The SKU, MPN, gtin, gtin8 (which is the EAN or bar code number), et la. Are all references that Google may already know about to unambiguously identify the product. Any or all may be used.

Google is going to try to look to identify the product under brand, and product name.  But clearly given how people enter things into online forms it may not see the correct product ... for a "Ford," "F150" it is such a well know product google does not need to look for any manufacturer product number for the part. But if we are talking about the gas cap for the F150 whatever numbering system Ford uses to identify the part when ordering it makes the reference unambiguous.

### Use what the manufacturer uses

On products that use bar codes, use the bar code; On products that use MPN use that, if they have an SKU that is published use that.

If they have more than one, it does no harm to use all the product numbers available but will not affect how Google treats the page ... it will fill in Google's database.

Comment: Thanks Wayne for clarifying it is not so important....I am in the "F150 gas cap" market so I fixed it by using the product id I provide to Google Merchant Center as SKU(as recommended by the Merchant Center Help section)...just strange that my competitors get away with it giving absolute incorrect info.